# convert solr parameter in browser to c# json

Tags: c#, json, solr

I write this URL in my browser:

```
http://localhost:9063/solr/Object_Collection/select?q=*:*&facet=true&f.DateRangeValue.facet.range.start=NOW/YEAR-10YEAR&facet.range=DateRangeValue&facet.range.end=NOW/YEAR&facet.range.gap=%2B1YEAR
```

It works...
but when I pass this URL in C# like this:

```
{
    ""Buckets2"" : {
        ""range"": {
            ""field"":""DateRangeValue"",
            ""start"" : ""NOW/YEAR-10YEAR"",
            ""end"" : ""NOW"",
            ""gap"" : ""+1YEAR""
                }
                    }
}
```

It does not work
}
}

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are you getting an error in the Solr log? How are you sending it to the server? Are you _actually_ using double sets of double quotes? What URL are you sending this to? Are you using SolrNet or something else? The question needs far more information for anyone to give a useful answer.

Comment: I getting Bad Request

Comment: {
 "Buckets" : {
 "type": "range",
 "field" : "DateRangeValue",
 "start" : "NOW/YEAR-11YEAR",
 "end" : "NOW",
 "gap" : "+1YEAR"
}
   }

Comment: The Bad request message will tell you more about what's wrong; but please add the details necessary about _how you're making this request_.

Answer (score 0):

you can use newtonsoft library to serialize to Json in standard way in C#

Comment: "Buckets" : { "type": "range", "field" : "DateRangeValue", "start" : "NOW/YEAR-11YEAR", "end" : "NOW", "gap" : "+1YEAR" } }

Comment: I getting BadRequest when I pass it to SOLR

Comment: The sample url which is work as you typed in your question is not json you have to pass query string to url and dont need to serialize it to json

Comment: DateTimeValue is OK but DateRangeValue is not

Comment: Unable to range facet on field:DateRangeValue{type=date_range,
properties=indexed,stored,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored}